# SQL Union - SemanticException 3:20 Schema of both sides of union should match

Tags: sql, hive, union, hiveql

I want to create a View with the following code but I somehow encounter errors which I cant really resolve.

**The code:**

```
create view default.table_all as 
select * 
from default.table_a
union select * 
from default.table_b;
```

**The Error:**

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 3:20 Schema of both sides of union should match: Column column_42 is of type double on first table and type string on second table. Error encountered near token 'table_b'

Firstly, column_42 is in both tables table_a and table_b the same data type, double (I already checked numerous times). Secondly when unionizing only on column_42

```
create view default.table_all as 
select column_42 
from default.table_a
union select column_42 
from default.table_b;
```

It works like a charm and does not show any errors whatsoever.

I really can't figure out the problem.

@Mureinik, here the DDLs of the two tables:

**DDL - table_a:**

```
createtab_stmt
CREATE TABLE `default.table_a`(`column_42` double, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://ITEG-EG-DC2-DR01-ns/user/hive/warehouse/table_a'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1635342670')
```

**DDL - table_b:**

```
createtab_stmt
CREATE TABLE `default.table_b`(`column_42` double,...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://ITEG-EG-DC2-DR01-ns/user/hive/warehouse/table_b`'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1635410688')
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the tables?

Comment: I just edited my post. Thanks a lot @Mureinik! :)

Comment: Try explicitly adding the columns to both queries one by one until the view errors and then you’ll see where the error is actually happening. As an aside, using select * is rarely a good idea as any change to the underlying objects can cause the view/union to break

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thank you very much! The thing is I am trying to create a view of about 200 tables, which will make it quite unreadable if I am adding each column in the select statement. But I will try my best! Have a great day! :)